# maven-ear-plugin create 2 ears out of 2 webModule (wars)

Tags: maven, pom.xml, ear

i have task which creates 1 ear out of 2 wars , i like to split this ear to 2 separated ears and that 
each ear have different war .

this is what i have:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <skinnyWars>false</skinnyWars>
    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib/</defaultLibBundleDir>
    <packagingIncludes>*.war,**/*.xml</packagingIncludes>
    <modules>
        <webModule>
            <artifactId>APP1</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <uri>APP1.war</uri>
            <bundleFileName>APP1.war</bundleFileName>
            <contextRoot>/APP1</contextRoot>
        </webModule>
        <webModule>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>APP2</artifactId>
            <uri>APP2.war</uri>
            <bundleFileName>APP2.war</bundleFileName>
            <contextRoot>/APP2</contextRoot>
        </webModule>
    </modules>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

**UPDATE**
what i was thinking to do is this but this not working at all :

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <finalName>APP1</finalName>
    <skinnyWars>false</skinnyWars>
    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib/</defaultLibBundleDir>
    <packagingIncludes>*.war,**/*.xml</packagingIncludes>
    <modules>
        <webModule>
            <artifactId>APP1</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <uri>APP1.war</uri>
            <bundleFileName>APP1.war</bundleFileName>
            <contextRoot>/APP1</contextRoot>
        </webModule>
    </modules>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <finalName>APP2</finalName>
    <skinnyWars>false</skinnyWars>
    <defaultLibBundleDir>lib/</defaultLibBundleDir>
    <packagingIncludes>*.war,**/*.xml</packagingIncludes>
    <modules>
        <webModule>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>APP2</artifactId>
            <uri>APP2.war</uri>
            <bundleFileName>APP2.war</bundleFileName>
            <contextRoot>/APP2</contextRoot>
        </webModule>
    </modules>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Usually, I would recommend just to use two separate ear projects. If you want to build this in one project, one of the EARs needs to get a classifier to distinguish it.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not really understand your question. Do you want to know what a classifier is? Or something different?

Comment: you mean to add classifier in the configuration section? 
i want to also to understand what you mean

Comment: I mean that I would recommend to have two separate EAR projects that each build an EAR. If you want build two EARs out of one project, than one of these EARs need to have an additional String as Classifier and its Maven coordinates are then groupId, artifactId, classifier, EAR, version. So you need to use the classifier to find that second EAR. I do not know at the moment how you achieve this technically, but I guess, you can add a second execution of the EAR plugin and then use the build helper plugin to attach the resulting artifact.

Comment: i did try to add another plugin execution and the final name but it don't work

Comment: No, you cannot add the plugin twice. You need to define an `<execution>` inside the `<executions>` in your plugin.